# How to access individual elements in a line in an RDD of type [String, (Int, Int, Int)]?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mapreduce, rdd

I have an RDD that is like this:

```
Array((math,(2,3,4)),(economics,(4,5,6)))
```

I want to access the integer elements and add them column wise. I tried with

```
var sum = rdd.map( (x,y) => (x._0+y._0,x._1+y._1,x._2+y._2)
```

but this doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? Is there some built-in function that does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get rid of the string column if you don't need it and then reduce the RDD by the elements:

```scala
val sum = rdd.map(_._2).reduce {
  case ((a, b, c), (d, e, f)) => (a + d, b + e, c + f)
}
```